# Error in receiving ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, sockets, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I am trying to create a client server program where I'm sending an object from client and receiving the object at the server continuously in the while loop.

Client code:

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
while(true){

            WorkerMessageToMaster message = new WorkerMessageToMaster(WorkerTasksStatus.getTaskStatusMap(), WorkerTasksStatus.getTaskStatusReduce());
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(taskManagerSocket.getOutputStream());
            oos.writeObject(message);
            oos.flush();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
```

Server code:

```
ObjectInputStream ois = null;
while (true ) {

            ois = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            WorkerMessageToMaster taskMapObject = (WorkerMessageToMaster)ois.readObject();
            System.out.println("Connection from: "+clientSocket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress().toString());

        }
```

When I try to run this code on my local system It runs normally, but when I try to run the client and server in different machines(different Ips) I get the following error.

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 74000432
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:804)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:299)
at master.MasterAnalyzer.heartBeat(MasterAnalyzer.java:58)
at master.MasterAnalyzer.run(MasterAnalyzer.java:80)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am confused at this erratic behavior as Im sending the stream through the client socket established with the server in a while loop and receiving it on the same socket connection accepted at the server and It seems to be working fine on local host.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Are all your Objects used in WorkerMessageToMaster serializable, as well as WorkerMessageToMaster itself? Every Object you want to send with ObjectStreams have to implement serializable, and all children of it have to have it implemented. String, as well as primitive datatypes (int, float etc) are serializable without you needing to do anything. But if you use your own classes, they have to implement serializable.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. All objects in WorkerToMaster are serializable i believe. 

    private ConcurrentHashMap<String, TaskDetails> mapStatus;
 private ConcurrentHashMap<String, TaskDetails> reduceStatus;
 private Boolean mapFull;
 private Boolean reduceFull;
Here task details is also serializable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a new stream for each object. Only create one output and one input stream. Object streams send header data which is maybe corrupted when you create a new stream.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. I found the issue. I had the PrintStream using the same socket Stream. I believe this was causing the corruption as when I removed it the issue was resolved.